# Boost Voltage of Signal Generator Output (via Audio/Signal Transformer?)

Tags: audio, boost, step-up, signal-generator

**Goal:**
Have a frequency variable voltage of at least 200 V (more would be great), between 50 Hz and 8 kHz (sine wave, as pure as possible). The voltage is used as open circuit voltage (only drives a couple of pF capacitive load).

**My Solution:**
I use a signal generator ([Rigol DG1022](https://www.batronix.com/pdf/Rigol/Datasheet/DG1022_DataSheet_EN.pdf)), which can provide 10 V (peak-to-peak) above 50 ohm output impedance. I would want to keep the setup as simple as possible (as I also do not need much power) and hence not use high voltage amplifiers (as [APEX PA92](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/156/pa92u-1853073.pdf)) or other commercial solutions (as [TREK PD07016](https://www.hvproducts.de/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/en-hv-amplifier-trek-pd07016-data-sheet.pdf)), which would be overpowered for my use case.

What I stumbled upon are Audio/Signal Transformers. From my understanding, there are offering what I am looking for, as they are quite frequency stable. From my understanding my constraints are

- at least a turn ratio of 10/200 = 20
- a low voltage winding resistance above 50 ohm
- frequency range between 50...8000 Hz

What I found are:

- [1140-MN-A](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/177/1140-1389973.pdf) --> I would 2 of those successively.
- [140MEX](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/177/140ex-1389953.pdf) --> I would 2 of those successively.

These look also promising, but I only got the impedance ratio and not the turns ratio:

- [808A](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/177/800a-1660970.pdf)
- [812A](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/177/800a-1660970.pdf)
- [560N](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/177/560-1389877.pdf)

**My Questions:**
As audio/signal transformers seem to be a whole different domain (from the specified ratings etc.):

1. Most importantly, do you think audio/signal transformers work for my application. Do you have a different/better idea?
2. Where do I find the maximum voltages I can apply to the transformer?
3. Where can I get more info on turns ratio (as I cannot derive the turns ratio from the impedance ratio)?

Comment: I would be concerned about the voltage capability of an audio transformer. None of these lists a voltage rating since for their intended use it is never a problem.

Comment: 200 Vrms, or Peak, or Peak-to-Peak?

Comment: At least 200 Vpp; 200 Vrms would be better and much more would also be great! What voltages are they usually used for?

Comment: @Maxim - Hi, Please stop adding a signature to your posts, as explained in [this](/help/behavior) site rule. Also, I recommend you review the site [tour] and the site [help] to see more site rules. There is further detailed guidance in the [Stack Exchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites). Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In a theoretically perfect transformer, the impedance ratio is the square of the turns ratio.  This is confirmed by most of the datasheets you linked.  A turns ratio (voltage multiplication or division) of 20:1 equates to an impedance ratio of 400:1.  That's a lot.  And for low distortion and wide bandwidth, that's expensive.

Most of the parts you linked are intended for low voltage transistor or opamp circuits.  This is not an automatic disqualification; the breakdown voltage between the primary and secondary could be hundreds of volts.  For max voltages, contact the manufacturer directly.

The 800a datasheet mentions "plates", a direct inference of vacuum tube circuits.  To me that says that these should be able to withstand 200 V between the windings, but only Hammond knows for sure.

Answer (score 3):

> *Where can I get more info on turns ratio (as I cannot derive the turns
> ratio from the impedance ratio)?*

If you have a step-up turns-ratio of \$1:N\$, the output voltage, \$V_O\$ is: -

$$V_I\times N$$

Because a transformer cannot create extra power, we can say that the output current is: -

$$I_I \times \frac{1}{N}$$

So, the output impedance equals: -

$$\dfrac{V_I\times N}{I_I\hspace{0.05cm} \div N}\hspace{2cm} = \hspace{2cm}\dfrac{V_I}{I_I}\times N^2$$

Or, the transformer output impedance is the input impedance multiplied by the turns ratio squared. This is the ideal case and real transformers are not quite as good as that but, squaring N is usually a fairly accurate way of predicting impedance ratios.

> *Where do I find the maximum voltages I can apply to the transformer?*

It gets a little more complicated here and, you have to consider the insulation on the secondary wires; it may breakdown if the output voltage is hundreds of volts or more.

At the other end of the scale, you don't want to saturate the transformer core and this means avoiding low frequencies where the applied input voltage is too high. Core saturation is due to excessive off-load primary current and, off-load current creates core magnetic fields.

Audio transformers can be run down to several Hz making them especially needy of high primary inductance to avoid core saturation. Any self-respecting transformer data sheet will tell you this and the limit values but, I'm not going to speculate without a target data sheet.

> *Most importantly, do you think audio/signal transformers work for my
> application.*

They sound the likeliest of the candidates. However, your options will be reduced by not having a signal generator with lower output impedance and, it may be necessary to have a driver circuit (like a small audio amplifier) between signal generator and transformer primary.

Answer (score 3):

Your turns ratio of 20 is pretty high...

A standard power supply transformer most likely won't have the bandwidth. You can always try with a 110V:5V transformer, they're cheap enough for quick experimentation and you may already have one somewhere.

You could use a transformer designed for the output of a tube amp, in reverse. These are likely to be quite costly, and the secondary impedance (which in your case will be the primary) will be closer to a loudspeaker's, 4-16 ohms. So your signal generator would need a booster amp. Here's an [example](https://fr.rs-online.com/web/p/transformateurs-audio/1237240?cm_mmc=FR-PLA-DS3A-_-google-_-CSS_FR_FR_Alimentations_et_transformateurs_Whoop-_-(FR:Whoop!)%20Transformateurs%20audio-_-1237240&matchtype=&pla-341431311492&gclsrc=ds&gclsrc=ds).

You could also use a transformer designed for the output of a tube preamp.

Due to the high impedance of the windings, the internal capacitance of the transformer matters a lot for a flat frequency response. This means... if you use them in reverse, you may not get the same frequency response.

Since transformer winding is specialist stuff (if you want wide bandwidth) I'd recommend asking a quote for a custom job at a transformer winding shop, like [toroidy](https://sklep.toroidy.pl/about-us) for example. Just explain your needs, your impedances, etc. You can always lurk on vacuum tube forums for more details.

If you can calibrate out the frequency response of the transformer by measuring the output voltage and adjusting the output of your generator accordingly, then that would relax the requirements on the transformer.

Note if you only need a tiny output current, making a high voltage amplifier isn't that difficult, and will most likely be cheaper. It's not that dangerous either if the power supply is limited to an adequately small current and the smoothing caps are downsized.

Comment: Since I had one sitting on my bench, I just tried a 60 Hz power transformer. It is probably 115/230VAC:12/24VAC (dual windings on pri and sec). Driving it with a waveform generator with 50 ohm output impedance, it works fairly well. There is some distortion at some frequencies, surprisingly worse at low freq. And the response is not flat, i.e. you need to adjust the amplitude for each frequency if you want a specific amplitude output.

Comment: @Mattman944: Thanks for the hint and the comment. I tried it with a 230 V / 10 V transformer myself but the signals became distorted pretty quickly. I will try it with what I answered at the bottom of the post. Thank you already.

Answer (score 1):

Audio transformer is a good solution if it doesn't matter that output amplitude will vary based on frequency and load. For stable output, a high voltage opamp would be good solution. It also has the benefit that you can get DC output voltage for other uses in the future.

PA92 mentioned in the question is expensive and unnecessarily powerful. Smaller output current alternatives such as [HV264](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Microchip-Technology-Atmel/HV264TS-G?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtOXy69nW9rM%2F0N842h6Up7M9Dh7xdCexU%3D) only costs 8 EUR and has output swing of 200 V. Because it has four outputs, you can bridge between two of them and get 400 V peak-to-peak output voltage.

You will need a high voltage supply, which should be limited to below 30 mA current for safety. I would use a 240VAC -> 240VAC isolation transformer and put two 4.7 kohm series resistors after it. A rectifier, small capacitor and a shunt regulator can be used to get stable 225 VDC supply for HV264.

It is probably useful to make the input tolerant of high common mode voltages. Low-distortion analog isolation is not easy, but you can use resistor dividers and a low-voltage opamp configured as differential amplifier.

Comment: Thank you @jpa. I like the flexibility of the OpAmp solution and that it is low cost. Can you recommend a recitifier and shunt regulator or would you build them yourself completely? Concerning audio transformer: the exact output voltage does not matter but it should be above 200 V....so if depending on saturation etc. I will get something above 200 V (which I can calibrate at each frequency) I would be fine...so really depends on how much output voltage varies. I would try to design a small op amp circuit based on your recommendation, would be great to hear your thoughts on this then!

Comment: @Maxim Now that I think of it, 3 watt zener diode would be simplest for the regulation (assuming the 2x4.7kohm series resistors). The rectifier can be any bridge rectifier or even single diode rated for mains voltage. The best layout is isolation transformer -> rectifier -> large capacitor -> resistors -> zener and small capacitor. But do remember that the part of the circuit before the current limiting resistors is a shock hazard, and even after them touching the wires will not feel nice.

Comment: Thanks again for your input! Really good! According to what you said I designed a circuit (unfortunately there is no spice model for the HV264 and I did not find a good alternative). See my circuit [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y3L87GKk0S9Qu_Fysb2rRDTJKyRINqgB/view?usp=sharing). Open questions are? How to do the bridging (is this not a parallel connection of sources then and hence not possible?). Can I also bridge more outputs (all 4)? Do I need to consider the input impedance of Vpp for my shunt regulator design then? Is it reasonable to assume inf? Thank you for the warnings!

Comment: @Maxim You don't really need R3 because R1 and R2 already limit the current. [Bridged amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridged_and_paralleled_amplifiers#Bridged_amplifier) means connecting one of the amplifiers in inverting configuration and connecting load between the two output pins. Typically you would bridge only two outputs, so it's up to you what to do with the other two.

Comment: Addition: Bridging would be necessary because from my understanding I would only get a 110 V Peak (220 V Peak to peak) with a 110 V DC Offset  out of one channel. Would also be nice to remove the DC offset.